# Sequence of events and all hooks made available in System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any explanation of the sequence of events that occurs in the creation, manipulation, and closing of System.Windows.Forms's various forms and components?  Is there an explanation of all possible hooks that I can override and the order they are called in and what happens in between their calling?

I've run into so many avoidable problems because I don't have a good understanding of what's going on under the hood here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [winforms - event life cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709263/winforms-event-life-cycle)

Comment: 1) read the books
2) place MessageBox.Show to every event handler of form and run application
3) investigate what is going on...
4) do this and many other things long time
5) you will get experience any way.

Luck

Comment: And turn on Microsoft .NET Framework source debugging!  Seeing their source code is invaluable.

Comment: Don't use MessageBox, it changes the event order.  Debug.WriteLine() is better.

Comment: @Paul I didn't know you could see the .NET framework source.  How do you turn that on?

Comment: How To: Debug .NET Framework Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening and closing an empty form under [Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) monitoring produces the following sequence of On* calls:

[image]

Typing "1" in a text box and pressing "Tab" to a button:
[image]

Closing a form with a text box and a button:

[image]

Comment: I don't guess you'd be willing to throw a text box on the form, type on it, tab away from the text box, and then close the form would you?

Comment: John, I've added interesting parts from a larger log for a form with a text box and a button. The following monitoring filter was used: "Function == On* && Class == System.Windows.Forms.* && Class != System.Windows.Forms.Internal.* && Class != ScrollableControl"

Answer (score 0):

Try these sources:

[Windows Forms Lifecycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/WindowsFormsLifecycle11182008235227PM/WindowsFormsLifecycle.aspx)

[Basic-events-in-the-Lifecycle-of-Forms-and-Controls](http://codebetter.com/blogs/paul.laudeman/archive/2005/04/17/Windows-Forms-_2D00_-Basic-events-in-the-Lifecycle-of-Forms-and-Controls.aspx)