# CreateGraphics() Method and Paint Event Args

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have read somewhere that `CreateGraphics()` will do this steps for us :

1. BeginPaint
2. Drawing
3. EndPaint

I have my code like this  :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grFrom = this.CreateGraphics();
    grFrom.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

There is no red rectangle...but, When I  copy line below in `Form1_paint`, every thing runs correctly.

```
grFrom.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, this.ClientRectangle);
```

So Question is Here:
What is the `e.Graphics` in `Form1_paint`?

`CreateGraphics` or `e.Graphics`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. [CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) gives you a graphics object that you should always `Dispose()` prior to exiting.  You should put your statement inside of a using block.
2. The graphics you draw are only valid until the form gets repainted.  In your case, by calling this in Form_Load, it's happening prior to the first render, and getting "thrown away".  You should always put this in OnPaint() in order to have it "persistent" on the screen, as that will cause it to get redrawn when the control is redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Your form load call is drawing to the form, but then the first regular form paint event writes over it, so you never see it. (As this happens before your presented the form at all)

> So Question is Here : What is the
>
> e.Graphics in form1_paint ?
>
> CreateGraphics or e.Graphics ?

I'm fairly sure the are equivilent, what you need is a better understanding of the windows forms event lifecycle.

This answer has relevant links:
[WinForms event life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709263/winforms-event-life-cycle)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new graphics object, which is most likely backed by a memory buffer. The Graphics objects you get from `e.Graphics` is backed by a buffer which represents the screen area by the current window (window as in Window Handle, not a window with title bar, etc).

You can always bit blit the data from a created graphics object onto the one from `e.Graphics`.

I am sure someone will elaborate much more than I have.