# Winform graphic rectangle large numbers and show them on form/panel/tab

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to draw dynamic rectangles of two different colour(red and blue) of size (10, 10 ) on winform. It can be more than 100,000+ in numbers.

As I draw them on winform or in panel, they starting to overlap. I've tried scrollbar but I am unable to do that. As I vertically scrolled them there shape starting to mess up. Rectangles could be many in numbers (row and column wise).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl2.Visible = true;

            Graphics g = FileInfoTab.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
        for (int y = 158; y < 1000; y += 15)
        {
            for (int x = 120; x < 280; x += 15)
            {

                Random rd = new Random();
                int nm = rd.Next(0, 10);

                if (nm % 2 == 0) //if number is even draw red rectangle else blue rectangle
                {
                    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, x, y, 10, 10);
                    g.FillRectangle(sb, x, y, 10, 10);
                    //x += 15;
                }
                else
                {
                    SolidBrush sb_1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, x, y, 10, 10);
                    g.FillRectangle(sb_1, x, y, 10, 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: increase number of rectangles ^ and show them in single form/panel

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  It's a temporary canvas.  Minimizing your form will erase what you have drawn, for example.  Use the panel's paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Graphics` object created from `Control.CreateGraphics()` must always be disposed before your code exits as described here: ([CreateGraphics() Method and Paint Event Args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352765/creategraphics-method-and-paint-event-args))

Maybe you should consider using the FileInfoTab.Paint event instead:

```
private Bitmap Surface;
private Graphics g;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RedrawSurface();
}

private void RedrawSurface()
{
    tabControl2.Visible = true;

    Surface = new Bitmap(FileInfoTab.Width, FileInfoTab.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bpprgb);
    g = Graphics.FromImage(Surface);

    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
    for (int y = 158; y < 1000; y += 15)
    {
        for (int x = 120; x < 280; x += 15)
        {
            Random rd = new Random();
            int nm = rd.Next(0, 10);
            if (nm % 2 == 0)
            {
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, x, y, 10, 10);
                g.FillRectangle(sb, x, y, 10, 10);
                //x += 15;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidBrush sb_1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, x, y, 10, 10);
                g.FillRectangle(sb_1, x, y, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    g.Dispose();
    FileInfoTab.Invalidate();
}

private void FileInfoTab_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Surface != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Surface, 0, 0);
    }
}
```